# Microsoft CCF on Azure unable to make initial user Active

Tags: azure

In order to do anything on a confidential ledger, you need to have at least one Active member. When you create a confidential ledger on Azure you also create a member (ccfbank1 is mine). It has a status of Accepted. To go from Accepted to Active, you need to call the /gov/state-digests/:ack endpoint with a signed digest of the latest state. Response is error as below. Any help appreciated.

```
ccf_cose_sign1 \
--ccf-gov-msg-type ack \
--ccf-gov-msg-created_at date -uIseconds \
--signing-key ccfbank1_privk.pem \
--signing-cert ccfbank1_cert.pem \
--content state_digest.json \
| curl https://myledger.confidential-ledger.azure.com/gov/members/state-digests/memberId:ack?api-version=2023-06-01-preview -k
--data-binary @-
-H "content-type: application/cose" 

{"error":{"code":"InvalidInput","message":"[json.exception.type_error.302] type must 
be string, but is number"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.  Documentation shows that the digest to be signed is

```
{
    "digest": <...>
}
```

In fact the digest should be exactly the one which is returned from gov/members/state-digests/

```
{
  "memberId": "48e862e9b...43eaf35",
  "stateDigest": "2c938987...8869fd56e0"
}
```